# Set Filename as Text within specific column of active row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save my workbook, with the filename being the address shown in the H column of another workbook. I want it to take the address from only the active row of that workbook.

[image]

This code was working. Now it only takes the address from H10 (highlighted box) even when I'm not clicking it. It is 8 rows down from the active row so maybe that's why but I thought the 8 referred to H being the 8th column and this worked initially.

```vb
Sub CREATE_REINTSTATEMENT_SHEET()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
'set source workbook - this is the planning sheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
'set workbook 2 as the new reinstatement sheet, taken from template
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add("filepath")

'Next we will save the new reinstatement sheet with the filename as the works address
    Dim Loc As String
    Dim FileSaveName As String
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim row As Integer
    row = ActiveCell.row
    Loc = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 8)
    fPath = "myfilepath\"
    wb2.SaveAs Filename:=fPath & Loc & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
```

It will come up with a warning if there's already a file called this. If so, need to save as manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference which workbook you want to use. In your code you do this:

```
'set workbook 2 as the new reinstatement sheet, taken from template
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add("filepath")
```

Everytime you add a new workbook it becomes the active one by default. So then your code does this:

```
row = ActiveCell.row
```

It will get the row number of active cell **from wb2**

Try activating the workbook first or getting the `Loc` variable before. maybe something like this:

```
Sub CREATE_REINTSTATEMENT_SHEET()
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim Loc As String
Dim FileSaveName As String
Dim fPath As String
Dim row As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
row = ActiveCell.row
Loc = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 8)
fPath = "myfilepath\"

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add("filepath")
wb2.SaveAs Filename:=fPath & Loc & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! :) If i then want to copy information from specific cells within the active row on the first workbook, into the new workbook, do i need to reset the first wb as the active workbook in the next line?

Comment: I have now tried to copy information from specific columns along the active row from the first workbook, and paste them into the second wb. The code runs without bringing up any errors but nothing seems to happen so i'm not sure what it's actually copying? Could you advise?

Comment: this is the code i've used directly after the code you've written above.

'Next, copy info from planning sheet active row into reinstatement sheet
'To do this, i first have to set the planner sheet as the active workbook again
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
row = ActiveCell.row

'CLIENT
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 4).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 23).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'WI NO
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 5).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 18).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: @LivHudson Please, if you have new problems you should open new questions and not use comments (these are just for clarifications). Anyways, the usual way to copy from 1 cell to another cell uses to be something like `wbSource.Worksheets("name").Range("A1").Copy wbDestiny.Worksheet("name").Range("A1")`

Comment: okay thank you, sorry i'm new to this